# At what phase and goal in Maven is the dependencies of the project downloaded?

Tags: maven

When I build a maven project, I see in cmd the dependencies download commands, but I do not see in which goal of which plugin the download is performed. And at what phase it happens ?

[image]

Comment: Usually, before the first goal is executed.

Answer (score 6):

Resolving dependency is Maven core feature is done during project model build (reading project structure).

So no plugin and no phase is applicable for dependency resolution - it is done before first plugin is run.

When some of dependencies was resolved early and are currently saved in `~/.m2/repository` - next downloading will not occurs, so you can not see `Downloading from ...` for next project build.

Comment: you saved my life.
it's a horror if you try to use the purge-local-repository-mojo and dom't know that you have no chance to be faster than the dependency resolution